# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender'

Tags: c#

I got this method here:

```
 public void textBoxValid(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string error = null;
    string pattern = @"\,\";
    if(Regex.IsMatch(priceTextBox.Text, pattern))
    {
        error = "Please use [.] instead of [,]";
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    errorProvider1.SetError((Control) sender, error);
}
```

And when I'm calling it here:

```
 private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxValid();
    //Write all data to a file.
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\event.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(priceTextBox.Text + "," + eventTextBox.Text + "," + descriptionTextBox.Text + ","
        + DateTimePicker.Value + "," + DayUpDown.Value);           
    }
    clearTextBoxes();                      
}
```

I'm getting an error saying:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'sender' of 'WriteEventForm.textBoxValid(object,
>   CancelEventArg)'

Could one of you, fine people, point out what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: `textBoxValid();` vs `textBoxValid(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)`? the parameters don't match. I mean the error tells you all you need to know right? `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender'`. Are you passing the argument `sender`? No, no your not.

Comment: Could you enlighten me? What am I missing, because if I use textBoxValid(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) instead. All text within the parenthesis get highlighted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `textBoxValid()`, you're calling a method that has two non-optional parameters with zero arguments. You can't do that in C#.

You seem to want to validate the input of a textbox upon the clicking of a button, and prevent that click event from proceeding if the input is invalid. Now to fix your code in a non-idiomatic way, would be to change the method entirely:

```
public bool ValidateTextBox(TextBox textBoxToValidate)
{
    string error = null;
    string pattern = @"\,\";
    if(Regex.IsMatch(textBoxToValidate.Text, pattern))
    {
        error = "Please use [.] instead of [,]";
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBoxToValidate, error);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Because the `sender` you have in `enterButton_Click()` will be the button, not the textbox. So you'll need to provide a reference to the textbox that you want to validate, and then inspect the return value of the method:

```
private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidateTextBox(priceTextBox))
    {       
        return;
    }
```

This will fix your problem for now. But then still you're not using the ErrorProvider as it's meant to.

Comment: Thank you, I do realize I probably make a lot of mistakes, I'm only a beginner, still have loads to learn. Thanks. Do you know any good resources that explain how to use ErrorProvider in the correct manner?

Comment: Just to correct, there is an error here: string pattern = @"\,\";
It should be: string pattern = @"\,";
Otherwise it crashes. My mistake.

Comment: I can't really find a resource this quickly that explains how to properly implement the Validating event and the ErrorProvider together, but that's the way you should be looking. Doing that, you can validate as users type, instead of only after clicking Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition:

`public void textBoxValid(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)`

Basics dude. This method needs 2 parameters (sender and args). Try this:

`textBoxValid(this, null)`

Try to pass something logic as sender. Try to set it to something that you call the `raising object` for this method. For the args you need to decide for yourself if you need them.

Normally `EventArgs` are passing side-informations to an event. Normally, this event is triggered by a control, not from code.

If this method isnt triggered from any control and you dont need any parameters, leave them:

`public void textBoxValid() { }`

Comment: Thank you for your time.